# cannot get rest service

Tags: rest, kotlin, tornadofx

This drives me crazy, I have 2 http requests in a sample application:

```
open class RestController : Controller() {
    val api = Rest()
    init {
        api.baseURI = "http://127.0.0.1:5059/"
    }
}
class PendingCtlr : RestController() {


    fun load(): ObservableList<PendingEntity> {
        val txt = api.get("pendings").list()
        val temp = txt.toModel<PendingEntity>()
        return temp.observable()
    }

}
class ConfirmedCtrl : RestController() {
    fun load(id: Long): ObservableList<ConfirmedEntity> {
        val li= api.get("confirmeds").list()
        val temp = li.toModel<ConfirmedEntity>()
        return temp.observable()
    }
}
```

The first one works, the second one doesn't even hit the application level, it gets rejected with `400 BadRequest` by my backend (Werkzeug).

I see absolutely no difference in both functions, and I can call both routes from my Swagger, as well as from python  as well as from curl! Could someone please advise at least where to look for debug?

**EDIT:**  The problem was on server side -_- Solved

Comment: Any details in web server logs?

Comment: You're using it wrong. You should do  `val api: Rest by inject()` in both controllers and ditch that `RestController` class. Somewhere in your app, for example in App.start() you can do `find<Rest>().baseURI = "..."`. Not sure this solves the issue, but it's a start. Then supply a complete test app so it's easier to figure out what's happening here. Also, your code is very verbose. The load function in ConfirmedCtrl could be `fun load(id: Long) = api.get("confirmeds").list().toModel<ConfirmedEntity>()`. That already returns an ObservableArrayList, so no need in calling `observable()` on that.